# how to configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

I'm installing Gawk-3.1.3 and used

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib
```

and the output was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Bdp.png)
or this

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... ./install-sh -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

my system is ubuntu 14.04 and the system details say the os is 32 bit. any help would be great as the compiler fails on anytime I try to use it, not just with this install.

Here's the config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU Awk configure 3.1.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.57.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = mikhanael-Aspire-4736
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.19.0-28-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:33:32 UTC 2015

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1356: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1410: result: ./install-sh -c
configure:1421: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1464: result: yes
configure:1497: checking for gawk
configure:1526: result: no
configure:1497: checking for mawk
configure:1513: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:1523: result: mawk
configure:1533: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:1553: result: yes
configure:1772: checking for egrep
configure:1782: result: grep -E
configure:1791: checking for bison
configure:1820: result: no
configure:1791: checking for byacc
configure:1820: result: no
configure:1828: checking whether ln -s works
configure:1832: result: yes
configure:1885: checking for gcc
configure:1901: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:1911: result: gcc
configure:2155: checking for C compiler version
configure:2158: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2161: $? = 0
configure:2163: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 
configure:2166: $? = 0
configure:2168: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2171: $? = 4
configure:2195: checking for C compiler default output
configure:2198: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2201: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| #line 2174 "configure"
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU Awk"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gawk"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU Awk 3.1.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-gawk@gnu.org"
| #define PACKAGE "gawk"
| #define VERSION "3.1.3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2240: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_egrep='grep -E'
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run aclocal-1.7'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run tar'
ANSI2KNR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run automake-1.7'
AWK='mawk'
BUILD_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
CATOBJEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATADIRNAME=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
GENCAT=''
GLIBC21=''
GMSGFMT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'
INSTOBJEXT=''
INTLBISON=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTLOBJS=''
INTL_LIBTOOL_SUFFIX_PREFIX=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBICONV=''
LIBINTL=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBICONV=''
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/missing --run makeinfo'
MKINSTALLDIRS=''
MSGFMT=''
MSGMERGE=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='gawk'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='bug-gawk@gnu.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU Awk'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU Awk 3.1.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gawk'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.1.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POSUB=''
RANLIB=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SOCKET_LIBS=''
STRIP=''
U=''
USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='3.1.3'
XGETTEXT=''
YACC='yacc'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
ac_ct_STRIP=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
install_sh='/home/mikhanael/packages/gawk-3.1.3/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE "gawk"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-gawk@gnu.org"
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU Awk"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU Awk 3.1.3"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gawk"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1.3"
#define VERSION "3.1.3"

configure: exit 77
```

Thanks, and bear with my bad english explanation.

Comment: ... and you need to build gawk-3.1.3 because ... ?

Comment: It looks like you have a non-standard version of the linker `/usr/local/bin/ld` that is being found in preference to the usual `/usr/bin/ld`

Comment: i want to do some CLFS and i need the Gawk to install iana-etc-2.30 and i realized that if i want to install iana-etc-2.30 i need at least Gawk 3.1. And i checked if i already have Gawk that i know that i didn't have in my system. 
By the way thanks for the answer and that really helped me! And i really didn't know those question already there :)


But, when i tried to install these packages some error was thrown out. Please bear with me because i want to  learn something new

Comment: No problem, learning is good - I just wanted to point out that you can install a pre-built package of gawk 4.0.1 directly from the 14.04 repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot, because i'm still new on linux and i want to be better at understanding linux. For the installation gawk i searched it maybe i didn't take a good look at it and missed it probably, thanks for the information though.